# iOS 11 ARKit : Drag Object in 3D View

Tags: ios, swift3, arkit

I have a node object in 3d view and i need to drag that object,
So far i have tried from here : [Placing, Dragging and Removing SCNNodes in ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509973/placing-dragging-and-removing-scnnodes-in-arkit)

and converted in swift

```
@objc func handleDragGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.sceneView)
        switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .began:
            print("Object began to move")
            let hitResults = self.sceneView.hitTest(tapPoint, options: nil)
            if hitResults.isEmpty { return }
            let hitResult = hitResults.first
            if let node = hitResult?.node.parent?.parent?.parent {
                self.photoNode = node
            }
        case .changed:
            print("Moving object position changed")
            if let _ = self.photoNode {
                let hitResults = self.sceneView.hitTest(tapPoint, types: .featurePoint)
                let hitResult = hitResults.last
                if let transform = hitResult?.worldTransform {
                    let matrix = SCNMatrix4FromMat4(transform)
                    let vector = SCNVector3Make(matrix.m41, matrix.m42, matrix.m43)
                    self.photoNode?.position = vector
                }
            }
        case .ended:
            print("Done moving object")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

but it is not working properly. what is the correct way to do?

Comment: I'm the one you linked in your question. It could be possible that your node has even more parents. At the time i just kept going up parent levels until it worked, so many you're still not grabbing the entire SCNNode. 

Try giving your node a name when you add it to the scene and debug what node you're getting from your hitresult, check if it's name is the same as the one you gave, and if not, go up a parent level till you find it. I'm sure there's a cleaner way to go about this, but I didn't have the time to do it then.

Comment: @AlanS : it's a basic view i have added a single node in sceneView that's it. All i need to do is dragging node

Comment: Yes exactly, but my code worked cause my nodes had several child nodes. You need to check to see whether your node is actually what you want it to be. Use breakpoints to see what the value is. 
Or try just doing hitResult?.node, if that doesn't work then use hitResult?.node.parent, etc.. until it works.

Comment: Have you tried changing the implementation at all?

Comment: i tried in coordinates but couldn't find the right things

Comment: try this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48220751/5567142)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using panGestureRecongniser... see basic swift Playground code for handling a SCNNode.

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport

public var textNode : SCNNode?

// Main ARKIT ViewController
class ViewController : UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {

var textNode: SCNNode!
var counter = 0
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // set the views delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self as! ARSCNViewDelegate
    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true
    // Create a new scene 
    sceneView.scene.rootNode
    // Add ligthing
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

    let text = SCNText(string: "Drag Me with Pan Gesture!", extrusionDepth: 1)
    //  create material
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
    text.materials = [material]

    //Create Node object
    textNode = SCNNode()

    textNode.name =  "textNode"
    textNode.scale = SCNVector3(x:0.004,y:0.004,z:0.004)
    textNode.geometry = text
    textNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y:0.02, z: -1)

    //  add new node to root node
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)

    // Add pan gesture for dragging the textNode about
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGesture(_:))))

}

override func loadView() {

    sceneView = ARSCNView(frame:CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 500.0, height: 600.0))
    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self 

    let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    config.planeDetection = .horizontal

    // Now we'll get messages when planes were detected...
    sceneView.session.delegate = self

    self.view = sceneView
    sceneView.session.run(config)

}

@objc func panGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {     

    gesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1

    let results = self.sceneView.hitTest(gesture.location(in: gesture.view), types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint)
    guard let result: ARHitTestResult = results.first else {
        return
    }

    let position = SCNVector3Make(result.worldTransform.columns.3.x, result.worldTransform.columns.3.y, result.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
    textNode.position = position
} 

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

**EDIT:**

The above drag function only worked if you had 1 object in the view, so it was not really necessary to hit the node to start dragging. It will just drag from where ever you tapped on the screen. If you have multiple objects in the view, and you want to drag nodes independently. You could change the panGesture function to the following, detect each node tapped first:

// drags nodes independently

```
@objc func panGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {     

    gesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1

    let results = self.sceneView.hitTest(gesture.location(in: gesture.view), types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint)

    guard let result: ARHitTestResult = results.first else {
        return
    }

    let hits = self.sceneView.hitTest(gesture.location(in: gesture.view), options: nil)
    if let tappedNode = hits.first?.node {
        let position = SCNVector3Make(result.worldTransform.columns.3.x, result.worldTransform.columns.3.y, result.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
        tappedNode.position = position
    }

}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162716/discussion-between-abhishek-thapliyal-and-ashley72).

Comment: This works but very badly, the object jumps all around. You are hit testing against .featurePoints so as you move the finger.. if it doesnt hit any featurepoint then it wont move, and then.. if with luck you hit a point.. it jumps. This is just not usable.

Comment: Dragging along axis -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825140/arkit-drag-a-node-along-a-specific-axis-not-on-a-plane.  I’ve also come seen answers for dragging along the plane.

Answer (score 1):

**REF:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/48220751/5589073

This code works for me

```
private func drag(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        let location = sender.location(in: self.sceneView)
        guard let hitNodeResult = self.sceneView.hitTest(location,
                                                         options: nil).first else { return }
        self.PCoordx = hitNodeResult.worldCoordinates.x
        self.PCoordy = hitNodeResult.worldCoordinates.y
        self.PCoordz = hitNodeResult.worldCoordinates.z
    case .changed:
        // when you start to pan in screen with your finger
        // hittest gives new coordinates of touched location in sceneView
        // coord-pcoord gives distance to move or distance paned in sceneview
        let hitNode = sceneView.hitTest(sender.location(in: sceneView), options: nil)
        if let coordx = hitNode.first?.worldCoordinates.x,
            let coordy = hitNode.first?.worldCoordinates.y,
            let coordz = hitNode.first?.worldCoordinates.z {
            let action = SCNAction.moveBy(x: CGFloat(coordx - self.PCoordx),
                                          y: CGFloat(coordy - self.PCoordy),
                                          z: CGFloat(coordz - self.PCoordz),
                                          duration: 0.0)
            self.photoNode.runAction(action)

            self.PCoordx = coordx
            self.PCoordy = coordy
            self.PCoordz = coordz
        }

        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.sceneView)
    case .ended:
        self.PCoordx = 0.0
        self.PCoordy = 0.0
        self.PCoordz = 0.0
    default:
        break
    }
}
```